# Python nested objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

this morning a encountered a strange behavior of python's objects (version 3.10.5). Maybe I am doing something wrong and I'd like to know what. Here's a mocked version of my issue :

```
class MyObject:
    list_of_subobjects = []
    name = ""

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def add_subobject(self, subobject_to_add):
        self.list_of_subobjects.append(subobject_to_add)

    def see_all_subobjects(self):
        print(f"In '{self.name}' there are {len(self.list_of_subobjects)} objects :")
        for subobject in self.list_of_subobjects:
            print(subobject.name)
        
objectA = MyObject("a")
objectB = MyObject("b")
objectC = MyObject("c")

objectA.add_subobject(objectB)
objectB.add_subobject(objectC)

objectA.see_all_subobjects()
# returns : 
# In 'a' there are 2 objects :
# b
# c
```

In my issue the object "MyObject" is a directory that can contain subdirectories containing subdirectories and so on. The directory B is added to A, then we add a directory C inside B. We should only see B when we ask which directories are directly contained by A, but the scripts outputs B and C. Is it because I add C inside B only after B is added inside A?

Thanks!

Comment: `list_of_subobjects` here is a class variable (shared by all instances of `MyObject`), not an instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the definition of `list_of_subobjects = []` and `name` inside the constructor (`__init__()`). Otherwise these two fields are class variables, i.e., they are shared by all instances.

This is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) with a very similar example.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.list_of_subobjects = []
        self.name = name
```

Comment: list_os_subobjects should not be cls variable